# Как изменить выбранную опцию в select?

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток.
Как можно выбрать соответствующую опцию в select при клике на одну из строк таблицы ?
т.е клик на 3 строке - выберется опция 3 и т.д

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector("table").addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  var td = e.target.closest("td[data-val]")

  if (td) {
    document.querySelector("select").value = td.dataset.val
  }
})
```

```css
table { display: inline-table; }
table, tr, td { border: 1px solid; }
td { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<table><tr><td data-val=1>First<td data-val=2>Second<td data-val=3>Third</tr></table>
<select><option value=1>Первый<option value=2>Второй<option value=3>Третий</select>
```